# Checking canvas dimension limitations

Tags: javascript, canvas

Discovering the Web Audio Api I wanted to draw a waveform for sound files. Now, I am aware of the image dimension limitations in some browsers, and I tried to look them up, but they seem to be ever changing (or at least memory differences like Chrome Desktop vs Chrome Mobile).

I tried to look up how to test if an image, or a Canvas / 2D Context can be of a certain size with almost no success. However, when testing this thing in Firefox I did get an error in the console so I tried the following method:

```
wfWidth = source.buffer.duration*100;
document.getElementById("waveform").width = wfWidth;
wfCtx = document.getElementById("waveform").getContext("2d");
var success = false;
while(success == false)
{
    try {
        var temp = wfCtx.getImageData(0,0,10,10); // this produced an error further down the code, so I use this as my test case.
        success = true;
    } catch(err) {
        wfWidth = wfWidth / 2;
        document.getElementById("waveform").width = wfWidth;
        wfCtx = document.getElementById("waveform").getContext("2d");
    }
    console.log(success);
}
```

This does seem to work in Firefox as the console first outputs `false` showing that the canvas is too big and then `true` after halving the width of the canvas and the waveform is shown.

However, in Google Chrome on Desktop the canvas seems to be of a certain size (as indicated by a scroll bar) but it is totally blank. When I right-click to save image, it is a 0 byte txt file. On Chrome Mobile (android) I get this little square sad face. Guess that method of checking doesn't work in Chrome.

What would be the best way to test if the canvas is, well, valid, and resize if it is not?

Comment: Can you just make the canvas whatever size you need to display e.g. 1024x768 and then scroll the desired contents into view as needed?

Comment: I guess this is as good a time as any to learn virtual scrolling.